# Singular locus of the Discriminant Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Everything can be assumed in $ \mathbb{C} $, or atleast in characteristic $ 0 $.

Consider degree $ d $ hypersurfaces in projective space $ \mathbb{P}^n $. These correspond, upto nonzero scalars, to homogeneous polynomials $ f $ of degree $ d $ in $ \mathbb{C} [ x_0, ... , x_n ] $. If $ M_d = \{ x^{\alpha} \} $, ($ \alpha $ a vector of $n+1 $ non-negative integers summing to $ d $) is the set of monomials of degree $ d $, these form a basis for $  \mathbb{C} [ x_0, ... , x_n ]_d $, so write $ f $ as $ \sum c_{\alpha} x^{\alpha} $. Then there is a homogeneous polynomial $D(d,n) $ in the coefficients $ c_{\alpha} $, called the discriminant  which satisfies the property that the hypersurface $ V(f) $ is singular iff $ D(d,n) $ vanishes. So $ D(d,n) $ itself defines a hypersurface in $ \mathbb{P}^{ \binom{d+n}{n} - 1 } $.

Question (1) : Is the hypersurface $ V (D(d,n) )$ singular always?

Here is an example, taking $ d=n=2 $, so we're looking at conics in $ \mathbb{P}^2 $. Write $$ f = ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 + dxy + eyz + fzx $$ Then one can compute $$ D(2,2) = 8abc + 2def - 2ae^2 - 2bf^2 - 2cd^2 $$ which defines a singular cubic fourfold in $ \mathbb{P}^5 $. The singular locus is given by the three rational curves on this hypersurface given by equations

$ a = d = f = 4bc - e^2 = 0 $

$ b = d = e = 4ac - f^2 = 0 $

$ c = e = f = 4ab - d^2 = 0 $

EDIT: What I wrote before was incomplete. The above description is not quite the full singular locus, as pointed out by Sasha. The singular locus is the $ 2 $-uple Veronese embedding given by $$ [u,v,w] \rightarrow [u^2, v^2, w^2, 2uv, 2vw, 2wu] $$ but this does not change the subsequent question.

We see that the singular locus corresponds precisely to the non-reduced conics. (Every conic, upto an invertible change of coordinates is either $ xy - z^2 $ which is isomorphic to a $ \mathbb{P}^1 $ or $ xy $ which is two intersecting lines or $ x^2 $ which is a nonreduced line.) This leads to my next question-

Question (2) : Does the singular locus of $ V(D(d,n)) $ correspond to nonreduced degree $ d $ hypersurfaces always?

Comment: This seems to be (twice) the A-discriminant (and not the X-discriminant or projective dual). See Gelfand, Kapranov and  Zelevinsky _Discriminants_, _Resultants_
_and_ _Multidimensional_ _Determinants_. On p. 437 they write: 
Now let $f (x, y, z) = a_1x^2+ a_2y^2 + a_3z^2 + a_4xy + a_5xz + a_6yz$
be a quadratic form. The A-discriminant $\Delta (f)$ can be computed from Proposition
1.7. We obtain
$\Delta(f) = a_1a_6^2 + a_5^2a_2 + a_4^2a_3 - a_4a_5a_6 - 4a_1a_2a_3.$ (1.13)

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland thanks, I didn't know of the A-discriminant, I just computed the condition for $ f $ to have a singular point by hand. But in any case, I think the questions still hold as my answer just differs by a scalar from theirs.

Comment: The singular locus of the discriminant cubic fourfold is not three curves, but a Veronese surface.

Comment: @Sasha thanks for catching my miss. They still correspond to nonreduced conics though.